# Using cocoon with modals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, cocoon-gem

I am trying to make a form using simple form where using link_to_add_association would show a modal to fill in the nested field, once he saves the changes in the modal the content should display in a div on the page and have edit/delete buttons, to create the modal I currently have this:

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'Add question', f, :questions, :partial => 'layouts/form/questions', class: 'link-add-field question .add-question', data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#questions-modal"} %>
```

The problem with using data-toggle and data-target is that what they do is just show a previously rendered modal, and when adding multiple of these it becomes a problem, is there a best practice to using link_to_add_association with modals? Should I use jQuery to make new instances of the modal whenever the link is clicked?

Comment: Not sure if it is clear to you how cocoon works: cocoon allows you to edit nested items in a single webform, _before_ sending it to the server. 

For what you describe, I would not use cocoon but just use ajax. It is a lot easier, because you just need to add a single item to a known parent.

Comment: Actually I need cocoon to use double nested forms, given a form where I can create many questions and each question can have multiple alternatives for answers(as in checkboxes or radio buttons), I was using cocoon for this in a single webform but changed adding a question to a modal to make less text field clutter in a single page view, I still need cocoon's functionality for the double nested form however